# How to store data in Django Model without having an input field

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I have model for example like this:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = u'Meetings'
        ordering = ['-date', 'team']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.date, self.team)


class Entry(models.Model):
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, blank=True)
    meeting_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = u'Entries'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am having a form I am controlling the input with

```
class MyEntryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Entry
```

I am getting the data for the meeting field with

```
meeting = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Meeting.objects.all(), empty_label=None)
```

I want to extract the date part of the meeting field (I am able to manage this). This date part should be the input for the meeting_date field. The meeting_date field has no input field in the form and should be populated automatically.
I don't know how to get this date extract into the meeting_date field and how to store it

The attempt in def clean(self)

```
cleaned_data['meeting_date'] = date_extract_from_meeting
```

does not work

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Are you planning on changing either meeting.date or entry.meeting_date at some point in the future? If not, then it seems you should just use entry.meeting.date instead of duplicating the data.

Answer (score 7):

There is probably a way to override the form save() method and put the date in at that step, but I can't find any examples of doing this.

A way that I know would work for sure is to pass in commit=False to form.save (this way the actual database insert doesn't happen yet):

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
```

Then you can set the meeting date and save the object:

```
instance.meeting_date = instance.meeting.date
instance.save()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1: I think this is one of the reasons why commmit=False is present in Django.

Comment: Looks good but I am still lost. Where is this located at. Is it in the MyEntryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm): or somehow in the class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

Comment: I got it:
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.meeting_date = str(obj.meeting)[0:16]
        obj.save()
That works. Thanks for your help